# Como puedo hacer para ver solo datos por mes en una tabla en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Me gustaria Implementar en mi proyecto, al momento de abrir una lista de datos solo me muestren lo que hicieron en un mes y que cada mes se actuelize.

Este es el Codigo pero no me funciona

```
 $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT u.idhistorial,u.fecha_historial,u.producto,u.valor_venta,r.idcliente,r.nombre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ene,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abr,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ago,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(u.fecha_historial) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dic
                FROM historial u 
                INNER JOIN cliente r 
                ON u.idcliente = r.idcliente
                WHERE u.fecha_historial BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59' GROUP BY u.fecha_historial ASC LIMIT $desde,$por_pagina")
```